# Show Hide Scollto Menu won't fire Normal Links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.
But when I test this menu out the absolute links wont trigger?
I'm using a jquery script to trigger the show/hide functionality of the menu and simultaneously adds and removes specific class names from a couple divs.

What I'd like to do is make it so absolute url's work for going to outside pages. I'm using my own internal pages with absolute path for testing.

```
<!-- START SHOW HIDE DROP MENU -->
<div id="mobileMenu" class="list-nav menu_hide"><!-- add class of menu_show, and simultaneously add a class of show-lockscreen to the screen class below. -->
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://jonnyb.org/index.php" id="item-1">Home Screen</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://jonnyb.org/index.php">Web Focused</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#websummary" class="scroll">Summary</a></li>
                <li><a href="#portfolio" class="scroll">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#weboverview" class="scroll">Overview</a></li>
                <li><a href="#webskills" class="scroll">Skills</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://jonnyb.org/music.php">Music Focused</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#musicsummary" class="scroll">Summary</a></li>
                <li><a href="#music" class="scroll">Music</a></li>
                <li><a href="#video" class="scroll">Video</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="scroll">Photos (coming soon)</a></li>
                <li><a href="#musicoverview" class="scroll">Overview</a></li>
                <li><a href="#musicskills" class="scroll">Skills</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#connect" class="scroll">Connect</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- END SHOW HIDE DROP MENU -->
```

Here is the simple JS I have implemented for the show/hide & scroll & a few other functions used.

```
/* ============================================================
SCROLL TO
=============================================================== */

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    // show and hide mobile menu
    $('a#triggerMobileMenu, div#mobileMenu li a').on('click', function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        $('#mobileMenu').toggleClass('menu_hide menu_show');
        $('#mobileScreen').toggleClass('lockscreen_off lockscreen_on');
    });
}); 


/*global $:false */
$(document).ready(function(){"use strict";

    $(".scroll").click(function(event){

        var full_url = this.href;
        var parts = full_url.split("#");
        var trgt = parts[1];
        var target_offset = $("#"+trgt).offset();
        var target_top = target_offset.top - 75;

        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:target_top}, 1500);

    });
}); 


$(document).ready(function(){ 

     $(window).scroll(function(){
         if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
             $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
         } else {
             $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
         }
     }); 

     $('.scrollup').click(function(){
         $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
         return false;
     });

 });


$(document).ready(function() {

    // the portfolio items
    var $container = $('#isotope-container');
    $container.isotope({
        layoutMode: 'masonry',
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: 127,
            gutter: 16
        },

        filter: '*',
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false
        }
    });


    // filter portfolio items
    $('#isotope-options a').click(function(){
        $('#isotope-options .current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');

        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({
            filter: selector,
            animationOptions: {
                duration: 750,
                easing: 'linear',
                queue: false
            }
         });
         return false;
    });

});


$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img.lazy").lazyload({
        effect : "fadeIn"
    });
});


$(document).ready(function () {
    //call this first so we start out with the correct visibility depending on the selected form values
    toggleFields();

    //this will call our toggleFields function every time the selection value field changes
    $("#projecttype").change(function () {
        toggleFields();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling preventDefault() on the event that is being passed in. That will block the default functionality of an anchor tag.

Comment: What would be best practice then to allow anchor tag functionality in one instance, but on a show hide menu or scrollto type case not allow page refresh or blinking like glitchy refresh. If I take off preventDefault() from either set of script then one on scrollto I get the glitch reload I mentioned. Or on the show/hide it won't allow that ability but will just try to go to the link pre-show/hide.

Comment: fyi... aspiring js/jQuery student.

Comment: You could just add a conditional. 

if { $(this).hasClass('scroll') ){
 evt.preventDefault();
}

Comment: Ok... I tried adding the line but I'm not having much luck with my limited knowledge. See added Custom JS above where I'm implementing it.